# Click cell in Google Sheets to open data in popup

Tags: google-sheets

Is it possible to have a cell that just says "click me" or whatever, which opens a popup so you can see the full data?

I want to keep all my data contained in one row per item, but one cell per item has a lot of information that would cause the row to then expand and be large.

Ideally I'd like to put a mini-spreadsheet inside the popup, but I doubt that's possible.

What are my options for containing a lot of data in one cell, which the user must click to access?

Comment: Have you tried "Insert Notes" or "Insert Comment" options?. Right click on any cell and enter the note or comment. These two options should open a small window of text that you have entered when you click or move the mouse cursor or on top of it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did play around with that. The problem is that comments are not editable, and the notes popup is very small for some reason.

Comment: You can edit the comments. I have added a picture for you as an answer in this post.

Comment: Perhaps this is of interest: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/67910/29140

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try "Insert Notes" or "Insert Comment" options. Right click on any cell and enter the note or comment. These two options should open a small window of text that you have entered when you click or move the mouse cursor on top of it.

You can also edit the 'Comment'. Please refer the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: I wish I could make the notes popup screen bigger and also change the font to be more readable, but I guess this will do. I can't really use comments because it's for collaborative use and comments are assigned to each user.