# Create a popup in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

How can I create a popup in Google Sheets using the script editor?
I'd like to show a popup with a personalized notification.

It should start like this:

```
function onOpen() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var menubuttons1 = [ {name: "exampleOption", functionName: "clear1"} ];
ss.addMenu("example", menubuttons1);
```

Comment: Hope this is what you mean 1999, can't be more specific. 
What do you mean with fluff, by the way?

Comment: It's about opening a new function from the menu. Opening that results in a couple of things, of of them I would like to be a popup.

Comment: @JorisF. What do you think about my answer?

Comment: @Rubén I think it's great but I noticed you didn't mention .toast or .show, so I posted another answer about them.

Answer (score 11):

The easiest way to show a notification in Google Sheets is to use the method [`toast`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#toast(String)) of the Spreadsheet object. Here's a simple example:

```
function onOpen() {
  var message = 'The current time is ' + new Date().toString();
  var title = 'Welcome to Google Sheets';
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast(message, title);
}
```

Upon a user opening the spreadsheet, this script shows this "toast" in bottom right.

[image: popup]

If you want to show something with more complex formatting, use the method [`show`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#showuserinterface) in combination with the `HtmlService`; the documentation page has an example.

Comment: The `prompt` and `alert` methods within the `SpreadsheetApp` can be of use as well.

Comment: I don't see them listed in [SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app) documentation...

Comment: They're part of the `getUi()`, see: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/67910/29140

Answer (score 8):

## Dialogs and Sidebars in Google Apps

> Scripts that are bound to Google Docs, Sheets, or Forms can display
>   several types of user-interface elements — pre-built alerts and
>   prompts, plus dialogs and sidebars that contain custom HTML service or
>   UI service pages. Typically, these elements are opened from menu
>   items. (Note that in Google Forms, user-interface elements are visible
>   only to an editor who opens the form to modify it, not to a user who
>   opens the form to respond.)

## Alternatives

Basically there are two alternatives for pop ups triggered from a custom menu: Alerts dialogs and Custom dialogs

### Alert dialogs

> An alert is a pre-built dialog box that opens inside a Google Docs,
>   Sheets, or Forms editor. It displays a message and an "OK" button; a
>   title and alternative buttons are optional. It is similar to calling
>   window.alert() in client-side JavaScript within a web browser.
>
> Alerts suspend the server-side script while the dialog is open. The
>   script will resume after the user closes the dialog, but JDBC
>   connections will not persist across the suspension.
>
> As shown in the example below, Google Docs, Forms, and Sheets all use
>   the method Ui.alert(), which is available in three variants. To
>   override the default "OK" button, pass a value from the Ui.ButtonSet
>   enum as the buttons argument. To evaluate which button the user
>   clicked, compare the return value for alert() to the Ui.Button enum.
>
> ```
> function onOpen() {
>   SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
>       .createMenu('Custom Menu')
>       .addItem('Show alert', 'showAlert')
>       .addToUi();
> }
>
> function showAlert() {
>   var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); // Same variations.
>
>   var result = ui.alert(
>      'Please confirm',
>      'Are you sure you want to continue?',
>       ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
>
>   // Process the user's response.
>   if (result == ui.Button.YES) {
>     // User clicked "Yes".
>     ui.alert('Confirmation received.');
>   } else {
>     // User clicked "No" or X in the title bar.
>     ui.alert('Permission denied.');
>   }
> }
> ```

### Custom dialog

From [2] (follow the link in references to get access to the links in the quoted text)

> The HTML service lets you serve web pages that can interact with
>   server-side Apps Script functions. It is particularly useful for
>   building web apps or adding custom user interfaces in Google Docs,
>   Sheets, and Forms. You can even use it to generate the body of an
>   email.
>
> ### Create HTML files
>
> To add an HTML file to your Apps Script project, open the Script
>   Editor and choose **File > New > Html File**.
>
> Within the HTML file, you can write most standard HTML, CSS, and
>   client-side JavaScript. The page will be served as HTML5, although
>   some advanced features of HTML5 are not available, as explained in
>   Restrictions.
>
> Your file can also include template scriptlets that are processed on
>   the server before the page is sent to the user — similar to PHP — as
>   explained in the section on templated HTML.

...

> ### Serve HTML as a Google Docs, Sheets, or Forms user interface
>
> The HTML service can display a dialog or sidebar in Google Docs,
>   Sheets, or Forms if your script is container-bound to the file. (In
>   Google Forms, custom user interfaces are only visible to an editor who
>   opens the form to modify it, not to a user who opens the form to
>   respond.)
>
> Unlike a web app, a script that creates a user interface for a
>   document, spreadsheet, or form does not need a `doGet()` function
>   specifically, and you do not need to save a version of your script or
>   deploy it. Instead, the function that opens the user interface must
>   pass your HTML file as an HtmlOutput object to the `showModalDialog())`
>   or `showSidebar()` methods of the Ui object for the active document,
>   form, or spreadsheet.
>
> These examples include a few extra features for convenience: the
>   `onOpen()` function creates a custom menu that makes it easy to open the
>   interface, and the button in the HTML file invokes a special `close()`
>   method of the google.script.host API to close the interface.
>
> #### CODE.GS
>
> ```
> // Use this code for Google Docs, Forms, or new Sheets.
> function onOpen() {
>   SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
>       .createMenu('Dialog')
>       .addItem('Open', 'openDialog')
>       .addToUi();
> }
>
> function openDialog() {
>   var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index')
>       .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
>   SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
>       .showModalDialog(html, 'Dialog title');
> }
> ```
>
> #### INDEX.HTML
>
> ```
> Hello, world!
> <input type="button" value="Close"
>   onclick="google.script.host.close()" />
> ```

## References

- [Dialogs and Sidebars in Google Apps - Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs)
- [HTML Service: Create and Serve HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/)

## Similar questions

[Show cell value on click](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/67891/show-cell-value-on-click/67910#67910)